# How not to block on sending messages to ZeroMQ socket regardless of other side being disconnected?

Tags: python, zeromq

I have example where messages are periodically sent to ZMQ PAIR socket on one thread and in another thread those are read when needed. I want to read only messages that are sent while another side is connected to the socket.

```py
import time
from datetime import datetime
from threading import Event, Thread

from zmq import constants
from zmq.sugar.context import Context
from zmq.sugar.socket import Socket

context = Context.instance()
pipe_left: Socket = context.socket(constants.PAIR)
pipe_left.bind("inproc://internal_inproc")
pipe_right: Socket = context.socket(constants.PAIR)


def periodic_write(quit_event: Event):
    while True:
        if quit_event.is_set():
            break
        time.sleep(1)
        pipe_left.send_string(
            f"{datetime.now().strftime('%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S')}"
        )
        print("message sent", flush=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    quit_event = Event()

    writer_thread = Thread(target=periodic_write, args=[quit_event])
    writer_thread.start()

    input("Hit enter to continue")

    pipe_right.connect("inproc://internal_inproc")

    count = 0
    while count < 3:
        print(pipe_right.recv_string())
        count += 1

    pipe_right.disconnect("inproc://internal_inproc")

    quit_event.set()

    writer_thread.join()
```

This is how it works now. That first message can be really old depending on when you hit enter, notice time gap between first and second message. I also need to terminate the process because it hangs on line where it writes to the pipe.

```
Hit enter to continue
message sent
08/31/2023, 17:14:03
message sent
08/31/2023, 17:14:18
message sent
08/31/2023, 17:14:19
message sent
```

What I would like to get

```
Hit enter to continue
message sent
08/31/2023, 17:14:17
message sent
08/31/2023, 17:14:18
message sent
08/31/2023, 17:14:19
message sent
```

Should I use some other socket type or configure sockets so that sent messages are just discarded when another side is disconnected?

**UPDATE:**
Changed code to send messages faster and to do couple connect-disconnect cycles.
Using PUB-SUB seems to give me what I want:

```
from datetime import datetime
from threading import Event, Thread

from zmq import constants
from zmq.sugar.context import Context
from zmq.sugar.socket import Socket

context = Context.instance()
pipe_left: Socket = context.socket(constants.PUB)
pipe_left.bind("inproc://internal_inproc")
pipe_right: Socket = context.socket(constants.SUB)


def periodic_write(quit_event: Event):
    counter = 0
    while True:
        if quit_event.is_set():
            break
        pipe_left.send_string(
            f"{datetime.now().strftime('%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S')} {counter}"
        )

        counter += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    quit_event = Event()

    writer_thread = Thread(target=periodic_write, args=[quit_event])
    writer_thread.start()

    count = 0
    while (count := count + 1) <= 3:
        input("Hit enter to continue")

        pipe_right.connect("inproc://internal_inproc")
        pipe_right.subscribe("")

        print(pipe_right.recv_string())
        print(pipe_right.recv_string())
        print(pipe_right.recv_string())

        pipe_right.disconnect("inproc://internal_inproc")

    quit_event.set()

    writer_thread.join()
```

```
Hit enter to continue
08/31/2023, 18:04:23 1404591
08/31/2023, 18:04:23 1404592
08/31/2023, 18:04:23 1404593
Hit enter to continue
08/31/2023, 18:04:27 3719732
08/31/2023, 18:04:27 3719733
08/31/2023, 18:04:27 3719734
Hit enter to continue
08/31/2023, 18:04:29 5222446
08/31/2023, 18:04:29 5222447
08/31/2023, 18:04:29 5222448
```